# How to sort a query result array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a array with results from a query from regular tables, for example:

```
id | Name | Department | Location | Email | Phone | Type | ..........and so on
```

I have the results in a query array, I can get the default query sorted, but I would like to ability to be able to resort that array as needed without having to keep re-reading data from the server, to cut down on traffic / speed things up.

Is there a native function that does that so I can go like:

```
sort(array by department ascending)
display array in nice format
```

Any ideas?

Comment: could you provide a `var_dump()` or `print_r()` of the array you are working with? It would help to know the structure of the arrays.

Comment: Why don’t you sort the results within the query? Or what query is this anyway?

Comment: I think he doesn't want to use the query again to sort it in some other way as he said he doesn't want to make requests to server again for sorting with some other criteria.

Comment: Here is a sample:
Array ( [0] => 3 [id] => 3 [1] => Mike [rep] => Mike [2] => Joe [name] => Joe [3] => Business [department] => Business [4] => Room 1 [location] => Room 1 [5] => Joe@compudatasystems.ca [email] => Joe@compudatasystems.ca [6] => 5196525664 [phone] => 5196525664 [7] => Visit [type] => Visit [8] => Coke [drink] => Coke [9] => Works in Compudata [notes] => Works in Compudata [10] => 0000-00-00 [lastVisited] => 0000-00-00 [11] => 2010-08-27 [nextVisit] => 2010-08-27 )

Comment: PS. How do I make my code sample look like code in comments?

Comment: "I think he doesn't want to use the query again" - but why not query the data sorted in the first place? There's esp. that `display array in nice format` in the description that rings my alarm bell. Is the data stored between requests? Or can't the original query be altered? What's the reason for not having the "right" query at hand? Maybe it's even worthwhile to do the sorting on the client side and avoid another http round-trip altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort it this way (since it is an associative array):

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
   return strcmp($a['department'], $b['department']);
}

usort($your_array, "cmp")
print_r($your_array);
```

Comment: Hi, I was considering something like that, but I also need to pass in a variable to sort it by, for example name, department, date, etc.

Here is what I had so far:

function sortArray($by) {
 function sort_items($a, $b, $by) {
  return strnatcmp($a['$by'], $b['$by']); 
 }
}

but I'm not sure how to pass in that $by element (name, type, etc)

Comment: @Murtez: Remove the single quote, from `$by` try like this: `$a[$by], $b[$by]`

Comment: How would I pass in that $by variable though?

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_multisort(), though you need some more processing as per your requirements.

Have a look at it http://www.phpf1.com/manual/array-multisort.html